# Androidstudio can not resolve dependencies after adding classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-authentication

I want to add classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2' in root level build.gradle file but after adding classpath it's continuously shows me Resolving classpath and than it gives me error of

**Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.**

My app level build.gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gmail.com.signingmail"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And my root level build.gradle is.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha5'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: try this one classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

and this line end of app gradle file :apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: you are using older version of google play services. 9.2 is latest i guess.https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup and plugin https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin. Update you support respository from android sdk manager and update google play services. use the latest libs

Comment: yes @Raghunandan 9.2.0 is latest.

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0' And classpath  'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' also not working error remains same

Answer (score 0):

Ok i resolved this issue this happens because of my antivirus software who is blocking connection of android-studio. i just turn off antivirus and now it's working.